# LostFocus does'nt work TextBox when selecting a TreeviewItem

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I need to solve a problem between the TextBox and the treeview. When I select the TreeView after the TextBox I don't receive the LostFocus Event (for the TextBox) why?

I have tried to play a lot with Focusable and the focusableManager but .... it didn't helped me.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="{Binding VariableA, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource BoolToHiddenConverter}}


<TextBox Width="78" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"  
    PreviewTextInput="HatchingDistanceBox_PreviewTextInput"  
    Name="TextBoxAWhoShouldLostFocus" BorderThickness="0.5"  
    BorderBrush="White" MinHeight="30" Height="30" Text="{Binding SelectedFamille.VariableA}"  
    utilities:InputBindingsManager.UpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressed="TextBox.Text">  
</TextBox>  

<TreeView  Name="TreeView_After" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}" Focusable="True"   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" AllowDrop="True" Background="#282828" Margin="15, 0,0,0" >
    <TreeView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
            <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="TreeViewItem_GotFocus"></EventSetter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Style>

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <utilities:TreeViewSelectionBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFamille}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="StrategyNamePanel" Mouse.PreviewMouseDown="StrategyNamePanel_MouseDown"   Width="200" Background="#282828" Focusable="True" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
                <TextBox  Name="StrategyNameBox" FontWeight="Normal"  FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"  MinHeight="30" Height="30" BorderThickness="0"  utilities:InputBindingsManager.UpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressed="TextBox.Text"></TextBox>                     
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditTemplate">
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Name="NamePanel" Focusable="True" Mouse.PreviewMouseDown="NamePanel_MouseDown"  Width="200" Background="{StaticResource DarkGrey}" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
                <TextBox Name="NameBox" FontWeight="Normal" BorderBrush="{StaticResource DarkOrange}"  FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" MinHeight="30" Height="30"  utilities:InputBindingsManager.UpdatePropertySourceWhenEnterPressed="TextBox.Text" ></TextBox>                      
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="TreeViewItem_GotFocus"></EventSetter>
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.DragOver" Handler="TreeView_After_DragOver"/>
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.Drop" Handler="TreeView_After_Drop"/>
            <EventSetter Event="TreeViewItem.MouseMove" Handler="TreeView_After_MouseMove"/>
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>            
</TreeView>
```

1. The LostFocus from the textbox work when I click everywhere except in the TreeView

2) The lostFocus work if I first select  a parent in the treeView and then a Treeview Item.

3)When I first select a treeViewItem and Then an Another treeViewItem there is no more LostFocus Event.

Why????

Comment: `Try LostKeyboardFocus` instead.

Comment: It's a focus scope issue. You must expand the focus scope at least to additionally capture the whole `TreeView`. So when you remove `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` from the `TextBox` named _TextBoxAWhoShouldLostFocus_ it should work with `TextBox.LostFocus` again. If you need to explicitly define a new focus scope then you should set it to nearest common parent of the `TextBox` and the `TreeView` (the `StackPanel`). But as I said before `LostKeyboardFocus` will always work since it is independent from the logical focus.

Comment: I think have founded the answer and will soon post it.

Comment: As I said before: remove `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` from the `TextBox` and you are good to go.